# How to use Lucene expressions in Elasticsearch within a query to filter a search by hour

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a bunch of indexed documents, each of which have a `startTime` field which is a date. I want to query for all documents after 9 PM, regardless of what day they are on. In my setup, I have groovy scripts disabled for security reasons, so I'm looking to get through this using [Lucene expressions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_lucene_expressions_scripts). This was my original attempt, which used groovy scripts...

```
{
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc['startTime'].getHourOfDay() > 21"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do I craft a similar query using Lucene expressions? I can see that we should be able to access `getHourOfDay()` on documents, but I can't find any solid examples of filtering by hour without using groovy scripts.

Comment: If you are worried about security, you can still add scripts w/o enabling dynamic scripting.Read https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-groovy-scripts-without-dynamic-scripting

Comment: Why can't you simply index an additional field "hourOfDay", you can not only apply direct filter but it will be pretty fast than scripts

Comment: @rahulroc You're right that I could do that, and it would probably be way faster.  I'd rather not have to re-index all my data at this point though, and the general point still stands that the elasticsearch documentation claims we can use Lucene expressions with little-to-no documentation around examples

Comment: @Richa Absolutely.  The powerful thing about dynamic scripting, however, is that I can write some code to generate these queries ad-hoc.  That's my preference